# mirror squared of a number and square of the mirrored number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The title of this post maybe confusing, so let me give an example, with $2021$ (and happy new year!):
$$2021^2=4084441$$
The mirrored number of $2021$ is $1202$.
The square of the mirrored number is $1202^2=1444804$, which is equal to the mirrored square of the number $2021$.
There are plenty of such examples...

My question is: **do these numbers have a special name**? (In French, my mother tongue, I found the expression "nombres carrément retournés"...). But what in English?

Comment: For English see [here](https://www.studyrankersonline.com/72256/and-strange-pair-numbers-such-that-their-squares-169-961-are-also-mirror-images-each-other) for example, or [here](http://www.mathematische-basteleien.de/squarenumber.htm). The name is *mirror numbers* there.

Comment: Putting [the first few](https://repl.it/@JosGibbons/UnpleasantSoulfulDos#main.py) into the OEIS gives [skinny numbers](https://oeis.org/A061909), but they're defined as the $n$ for whcih long multiplication calculates $n^2$ without carries, so it's not obvious the sequences are identical.

Comment: @Andrew should we ask more if there are finitely many numbers like this?

Comment: Another curio for $2021$ which you can post in a new chat room where such curios are collected.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Actually, my sole question was about a specific term/name/denomination for this kind of numbers (12, 13, 21, 31, 102, 103, 112, 113, 122 and so on, have the same property...); apparently they have no particular name. Let's call them "square-reversible numbers".